# Cannot make out this error code

Tags: php, panel

I tried get a script to work. I payed $45.00 for keep getting an error on this line when uploading.

`if(empty($this->GetData('UserImage'))) {`

Execute this code, I get message:

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in
>   /home/wwwjcpsocials/public_html/files/functions.php on line 162

Comment: Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in /home/wwwjcpsocials/public_html/files/functions.php on line 162

Comment: not enough code/information to provide a solution. You probably don't want to show your full code because you paid for it, but there isn't much we can do with one line of code.

Comment: public function GetImage($UserID = false, $ImageWidth = false, $ImageHeight = false)
 {
  if(empty($this->GetData('UserImage'))) {
   echo '<img id="user-avatar" src="images/lock_thumb.jpg" alt=""/>';
  } else {
   $img = base64_encode(stripslashes($this->GetData('UserImage')));
   echo '<img id="user-avatar" width="'.$ImageWidth.'px;" height="'.$ImageHeight.'px;" src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64, '.$img.'"/>';

Comment: place your code in an edit http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36180943/edit rather than in comments please. and the use of public implies a class

Answer (score 2):

This happend because you can't check if a `return` or `echo` is empty while calling to a function/class. Example:

This for example will return a fatal error:

```
function isEmpty() {
    return "";
}

// This will return: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context
if(empty(isEmpty())) {
    echo "The function returned an empty string";
}
```

How you should check if the function returning no value the right way? Example:

```
function isEmpty() {
    return "";
}

// Because you have an variable
// You can check if the variable is empty.
$var = isEmpty();
if(empty($var)) {
    echo "The variable is empty.";
}
```

To fix your problem you should add a new variable before calling the `if` statement, for example `$userImage = $this->GetData('UserImage');`

Then replace `if(empty($this->GetData('UserImage'))) {` to this: `if(empty($userImage)) {`

> **Note:** It depends on what PHP version you are running on your server. Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Depends on PHP version, https://3v4l.org/sTFiJ.

Comment: @chris85 Aha, didn't knew that, thanks for your feedback! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = $this->GetData('UserImage');
if(empty($var)) {
```

Comment: Code only answers aren't very beneficial. You should explain the issue so the user knows why your code should be used, otherwise might be back tomorrow with a similar issue.